# Tablesorter filter displaying but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, widget, tablesorter

I'm stuck in this situation: I installed tablesorter, and initialized the filter widget. It is correctly displaying, and it is possible to sort the columns, but the filter won't sort anything.

Any ideas ? Thanks !

My header :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
```

My javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#tablesorter").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 

$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: [ "filter"]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616933/4904996) would help. Add the following to your css file:

```
/* rows hidden by filtering (needed for child rows) */
.tablesorter .filtered {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I spent so much time on this.. why would this not be the default behavior??  Anyway.. thank you so much for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

Don't initialize tablesorter twice. The second time it is initialized, all options are ignored.

Change your code to this:

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    widgets: [ "filter"]
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping ! That a good first step. The filters do indeed appear, but they are not effective yet... When I type something, nothing happens, even when clicking "Enter"....

Comment: Try including the [`debug` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#debug) and look in your browser console.